# UI Toolkit, Get the topmost Element under the cursor

Tags: unity

Basically, I'm making a small node system, Just for fun.

And I need to know if I can get the topmost Element under the cursor. I need it to connect nodes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the answer seems to be [IPanel.Pick](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UIElements.IPanel.Pick.html?_ga=2.219210333.51025220.1598878666-920942621.1597998263)

```
var picked = rootVisualElement.panel.Pick(evt.mousePosition);
```